# Blazor How Get all route urls from razor pages in blazor server side project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I encountered such a problem. I need to get a list of all url-route from razor pages with value of attribute Authorize
Such as

```
@page "/counter" 
@attribute [Authorize("IsAdmin")]
```

I try to do it by EndpointsDataSource, but not getting the right result

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing 
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels 
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages 
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 
@using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing 
@inject EndpointDataSource EndpointsDataSource

<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Order</th>
            <th scope="col">Display Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Route Pattern</th>
            <th scope="col">Metadata</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var endpoint in Endpoints)
        {
            var routeEndpoint = endpoint as RouteEndpoint;
            <tr>
                <td>@routeEndpoint?.Order</td>
                <td>@endpoint.DisplayName</td>
                <td>@routeEndpoint?.RoutePattern.RawText</td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var md in endpoint.Metadata)
                        {
                            switch (md)
                            {                               
                                case PageRouteMetadata prm:
                                    <li>
                                        <p>@nameof(PageRouteMetadata)</p>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Page Route: @prm.PageRoute</li>
                                            <li>Route Template: @prm.RouteTemplate</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    break;
                                case PageActionDescriptor pad:
                                    <li>
                                        <p>@nameof(PageActionDescriptor)</p>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Id: @pad.Id</li>
                                            <li>Area: @pad.AreaName</li>
                                            <li>Display Name: @pad.DisplayName</li>
                                            <li>View Engine Path: @pad.ViewEnginePath</li>
                                            <li>Relative Path: @pad.RelativePath</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    break;
                                case RouteNameMetadata rnm:
                                    <li>
                                        Route Name Metadata: @rnm.RouteName
                                    </li>
                                    break;
                                case SuppressLinkGenerationMetadata slg:
                                    <li>
                                        suppress link: @slg.SuppressLinkGeneration;
                                    </li>
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    <li>@md.ToString()</li>
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>    

@code{   
    public List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Endpoint> Endpoints { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Endpoints = EndpointsDataSource.Endpoints.ToList();        
    }
}
```

But I don’t even get a list of route urls, not to mention the attribute value. Can anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you know about this own system? How does it use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the code in the Index component with the following code, and add this directive to the FetchData component: @attribute [Authorize]

```
 @page "/"
 @using System.Linq;
 @using System.Reflection;


 <button type="button" @onclick="@GetRouteUrlWithAuthorizeAttribute">Get Route 
     Url With Authorize Attribute</button>

 @code{

      private Task GetRouteUrlWithAuthorizeAttribute()
      {

          // Get all the components whose base class is ComponentBase
          var components = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                 .ExportedTypes
                                 .Where(t => 
                                t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ComponentBase)));

          foreach (var component in components)
          {
              // Print the name (Type) of the Component
              Console.WriteLine(component.ToString());

             // Now check if this component contains the Authorize attribute
             var allAttributes = component.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true);

             var authorizeDataAttributes = 
                             allAttributes.OfType<IAuthorizeData>().ToArray();

             // If it does, show this to us... 
             foreach (var authorizeData in authorizeDataAttributes)
             {

                Console.WriteLine(authorizeData.ToString());
             }
        }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }

 }
```

If you're using the default Blazor template, the output should be:

XXX.App

XXX.Shared.MainLayout

XXX.Shared.NavMenu

XXX.Pages.Error

XXX.Pages.FetchData

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute**

XXX.Pages.Index

Hope this helps...